# How to use a class declared in in latter part of the header file from another class in top

Tags: c++, class

This is a class named `A`

```
class A {
    int x;
}
```

and a class `B`, it have  class A array member.

```
class B {
    A a[10];
    int y;
}
```

At the constructor of A, I need to use B. How can I do it ?

Comment: Add a constructor in `B` that calles the constructor in `A` to set `x`?

Comment: sorry maybe I didn't make my problem clear enough, I mean that when construct class A, I have to use the variable y in the class B ,but class A didn't have any variable to save the y.the x is not used to save y, it's just a example.

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. Can you give a concrete example of why you are trying to do this?

Comment: Do you know what a constructor is and what you can do there? If not, reasearch that topic a bit. Also, can you even set the `x` in a single `A` instance? As it stands, you can't, so I'd try to solve that problem first.

Comment: I think you should better frame up your Question and get an idea what are you trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

This code maybe help you.

```
 class A
    {
    public:
        int x;
    };

    class B : public A
    {
    public:
    A a[10];
    int y;
    A::x;

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I construct class A , I have to use the variable y in class B and make x = y.

See comments in code for how this relates:

```
class B;  // forward declare B - just saying it's a class

class A
{
  public:           // class B; above lets constructor take B&
    A(const B& b);  // declare but don't define constructor
  private:
    int x;
};

class B
{ ...definition as in Qn... };

// now we know exactly what B is, we can define the constructor

A::A(const B& b) // "when I construct... in class B"
  : x(b.y)       // "use the variable y and make x = y
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem here is that you have an array. In this case there is simple solution. You should iterate your array and, for every element in array, do what you want:

```
//Title of this code
//clang 3.4

#include <iostream>

class A {
    int x;
public:
    A(int x_value = 0)
        : x{x_value}
    {
    }

    int x_value() const {return x;}
    void set_x_value(int x_value) {x = x_value;}

};
class B {
    A a[10];
    int y;

public:
    B(int y_value)
        : y{y_value}
    {
        for(auto& a_instance : a)
            a_instance.set_x_value(y);
    }

    void print_all_a() const
    {
        for(auto a_instance : a)
            std::cout << a_instance.x_value() << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b{10};
    b.print_all_a();
}
```

Here is live example: http://rextester.com/VVEW75722

Answer (score 0):

Use forward deceleration.

```
class B;
class A {
    int x;
    A(B &b); //inside constructor you can use B to init A's values
}
class B {
    A a[10];
    int y;
}
```